# Is the relationship between impedance and three phase apparent power different in Delta and Wye?

Tags: three-phase

I looked up this article https://www.electricalpereview.com/base-impedance-single-three-phase-values-equal/ and I am really confused about the final equation.
[image]
The author says that this applies for both Delta and Wye but wouldn't the Delta formula be multiplied by 3 on the right side like below:
[image]